# Binding to ElementName located far in the VisualTree from a MenuItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

Here is the layout sketch of my application:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>...</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>...</Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border>...</Border>
        <Grid>...</Grid>
        <DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="myDataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyModel.Files}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFile}"                     
                  Margin="0,0,10,3" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle_Generic}"
                  IsReadOnly="True">...</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid>
        <Border>...</Border>
        <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,0,10,0">
            <Grid Margin="0,0,10,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>...</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>...</Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,10,2">
                    <Button>...</Button>
                    <Button Margin="0" Name="m_DropDownButton" Padding="0, 4"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"                            
                            ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="False" Click="m_DropDownButton_Click">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Path x:Name="BtnArrow" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="6" Fill="#FF000000" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z "/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Button.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="All files" Command="{Binding AllFilesCommand}" />
                                <MenuItem Header="Selected files only" 
                                          Command="{Binding SelectedFilesOnlyCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItems, ElementName=myDataGrid}"/>          
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Button.ContextMenu>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,10,0">...</StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I'd like to pass the `SelectedItems` property of `myDataGrid` as a CommandParameter in `myMenuItem`'s Command. How can I achieve this?

Note #1: These two controls are located far in the Visual Tree and their first common parent is `myGrid`. Couldn't find any working solution for this because I'm always getting the "Cannot find source for binding" error message in the output window.

Note #2: The `SelectedItems` property of DataGrid is readonly therefore it is not allowed to bind it to a ViewModel property.

Note #3: I'd like to avoid any code behind code such as creating an event handler for DataGrid's `SelectionChanged` event.

Comment: Is the above sketch a XAML document, or just a visual tree dump?

Comment: Why would you do that? A `ContextMenu` is a contextual menu... its context should change and relate to the place where you right click. So why would you provide right click options for `DataGrid` items on a `Button` that is in a different `Panel`? Just put the `ContextMenu` on the `DataGrid` where it belongs and all of your problems will disappear.

Comment: @Sheridan That context menu is a "dropdown" menu for a button. The button does some business logic with the data present in the grid. However in the context menu the user can select between "all items" and "selected items". Why is the context menu? This was a fairly cheap solution for having a control similar to WPF Toolkit's DropDownButton. I'm interested in the solution instead.

Comment: @MarioVernari It's a sketch. It's a XAML document with missing nodes and attributes. The original code would have been too long to paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not try the Sheridan's way, and it's worth a read IMHO.

Anyway, you may also try the below hack:

```
                <Button Margin="0" Name="m_DropDownButton" Padding="0, 4"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"                            
                        ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="False" Click="m_DropDownButton_Click"
                        Tag="{Binding ElementName=myDataGrid}"
                        >
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Path x:Name="BtnArrow" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="6" Fill="#FF000000" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z "/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Button.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="All files" Command="{Binding AllFilesCommand}" />
                            <MenuItem Header="Selected files only" 
                                      Command="{Binding SelectedFilesOnlyCommand}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.SelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </Button.ContextMenu>
                </Button>
```

Note the "Tag" attribute on the button and the CommandParameter binding.

There's also a little code-behind, but I believe you have it as well:

```
    private void m_DropDownButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (Button)sender;
        button.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = button;
        button.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You have a tricky requirement to fulfil, but there *is* a solution. It's kind of long and maybe a little painful too as you'll have a fair amount of work to do, but here it is.

Because the `ContextMenu` is not part of the normal visual tree, it has no access to the elements defined there, or the members of the `DataContext`. To fix the problem, there are two (or three) things that you have to do. The first thing is to add a property to your view model to data bind to the `DataGrid.SelectedItems` property.

The second thing that you have to do is to create a way to have `TwoWay Binding` on the `DataGrid.SelectedItems` property, because the 'built-in' one is read only. Luckily, there are many posts on this topic online, involving the use of a custom bindable `SelectedItems` Attached Property. I'll assume that you can find them yourself.

So, now assuming that you have access to the selected items in the view model, or code behind, you next need to set the `ContextMenu.DataContext` property to the instance of your view model. We can do that using the `ContextMenu.PlacementTarget` property and the ever useful `Tag` property... try this:

```
<Button Tag="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type 
    Views:YourView}}}">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={
            RelativeSource Self}}">
            <MenuItem />
            <MenuItem Name="myMenuItem" Command="{Binding DoAction}" 
                CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

The `Binding` in the `Tag` property will look to bind to the content of the `DataContext` property of the parent view (`Window` or `UserControl`), assuming that it were named `YourView` and you had set up an XML Namespace Prefix for your views project or folder named `Views`.

Next, the `ContextMenu.DataContext` is set to that same value from the `Tag` property and so now your `ContextMenu` has access to both the `SelectedItems` property *and* the commands from the view model.